# How to load static image in Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component that takes a prop string that is an url. It could be either a remote picture or a local static assets from the asset folder.

Directory structure:

```
-assets/
     - logo.png
-app.vue
-components/
    -ImageTest.vue
```

ImageTest.vue

```
  <template>
    <div>

        {{imagelink}}
        <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: red">
            <img :src="imglink" alt="" height="150px" width="150px">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ImageTest",
        props:{
            imagelink: String,
        },
        computed: {
            // a computed getter
            imglink: function () {
              console.log(this.imagelink)
                return (this.imagelink)
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <ImageTest imagelink="./assets/logo.png" ></ImageTest>
        <ImageTest imagelink="https://static.raymondcamden.com/images/banners/gate.jpg" ></ImageTest>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ImageTest from './components/ImageTest.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
            ImageTest
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Output: (The static file does not work, but I can see from the developer inspector tool that the url is loaded in the src)

[image]

Comment: did you try using `@/assets/logo.png` ?

Comment: I tried already. In the browser all picture that has loaded are showing as, /img+filename+hash.jpg or .png . not assets/filename.png for example localhost:8080/img/logo.64c8535c.png . does that give any clue ? –

Comment: I'm sorry, the link should be `imagelink="require('@/assets/logo.png')"`

Comment: Have you tried `imagelink="../assets/logo.png"`?

Comment: @Derek I tried that and now I get errors in the console.  Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/logo.png'"

found in

---> <ImageTest> at src/components/ImageTest.vue
       <App>
         <Root>

Comment: @admcfajn yes I did

Comment: Could you post your webpack config? This is using vuex, right?

Comment: @admcfajn where do I find my webpack config? I just used vue/cli to create my project and used the default setting

Comment: It's probably in a node module then. One of the packages in your package.json will point you towards it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193170/discussion-between-admcfajn-and-tsr).

Answer (score 0):

Since the image link is actually utilized within the `ImageTest.vue`, you may need to remove the dots.

This

```
<ImageTest imagelink="./assets/logo.png" ></ImageTest>
```

becomes

```
<ImageTest imagelink="/assets/logo.png" ></ImageTest>
```

Comment: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '../assets/logo.png'"

Comment: try with no dots, `/assets/logo.png`. I'm out of guesses after dat.

Comment: nothing works. In the browser all picture that has loaded are showing as, /img+filename+hash.jpg or .png . not assets/filename.png for example  http://localhost:8080/img/logo.64c8535c.png . does that give any clue ?